# Python DataFrame: Assign values to column based on number of rows present?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a df with three columns `name`,`day`,`status`

```
            name      day      status
    0       boyle      1         yes
    1       boyle      2         no
    2       boyle      7         yes
    3       boyle      5         yes
    4       boyle      7         no
    5       holt       5         yes
    6       amy        1         no
    7       amy        5         yes
    8       amy        6         yes
    9       terry      4         no
```

I'm trying to assign values - `True/False` to each row.

True - If `name` has a single record present.

False - If there are more than one record present with same name .

Resultant Output:

```
            name      day      status     result
    0       boyle      1         yes       False 
    1       boyle      2         no        False
    2       boyle      7         yes       False
    3       boyle      5         yes       False
    4       boyle      7         no        False
    5       holt       5         yes       True
    6       amy        1         no        False
    7       amy        5         yes       False
    8       amy        6         yes       False
    9       terry      4         no        True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`df.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` and invert(`~`) it:

```
df['result'] = ~df['name'].duplicated(keep=False)
```

Or with `value_counts` and `series.map`

```
df['result'] = df['name'].map(df['name'].value_counts().eq(1))
```

---

```
print(df)

    name  day status  result
0  boyle    1    yes   False
1  boyle    2     no   False
2  boyle    7    yes   False
3  boyle    5    yes   False
4  boyle    7     no   False
5   holt    5    yes    True
6    amy    1     no   False
7    amy    5    yes   False
8    amy    6    yes   False
9  terry    4     no    True
```